# From where MS Installer checks the need of a reboot?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installer

Actually the question'd arised when I was trying to install TMG (Thread Management Gateway) services which I think is irrelevant to TMG.

Here is the story:

I started the installer. After initialization, it warned me that I need to do a reboot. So I did a reboot. After that I started the installtion again, hoping to see the installation wizard, but installer says me that I need to reboot my computer, again. This drew some suspicions but me trusting the installer did a healthy reboot, again. I was upset when I started the installation 3rd time and saw that handsome need of a reboot warning dialog 3rd time. So, I decided to disable some services which might be affecting "need of a reboot" status, like startup programs like anti-virus. Rebooted, started installer 4th time and guess what? That little warning dialog appears 4th time...

Things escalated when I tried to install SQL Server, which I know it's installer checks the "need of a reboot" status, and warned again with that annoying "your computer needs a reboot" dialog!

The events made me curious and a question takes form: From where that little b..rd checks the need of a reboot status, actually? Registry? File system? It'll feel good if I can be able to alter that status and cheat the installer, saying "Bring it ooon, you installer!!..."

Edit:

My O.S. is x64 Windows 7 Ultimate Sp1 and up to date. Which service I was trying for is TMG Management services only, not firewall nothing else. Just remote management.

Comment: What's your operating system? There are some restrictions about TMG. For example you should install SP1 for Windows Server 2008 x64 edition. Please give us some more spesific information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows creates a value called `PendingFileRenameOperations` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`. Some Setups check if this value is preset and ask you first to reboot to process the pending operations.

Comment: Is it the only value that some setups check for or are there any other flags involved Reboot status?

Comment: Maybe the flag `DVDRebootSignal` is also used. But i don't know it for sure: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&tmp_geoLoc=true&docname=c00192792

Comment: Yeah, that's it.. Not DVDRebootSignal but PendingFileRenameOperations. Thank you, this was helpful.